# template deduction failed on std::ranges::transform on two vectors

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

The following code fail to compile on gcc 12.2.0

```cpp
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<bool> v1 = {true, false, false, true};
    vector<bool> v2 = {false, false, true, true};
    ranges::transform(v1, v2, v1.begin(), logical_and());
}
```

compiler shows bunch of possible candidates and failed reasons but I can't understand why it failed.

Replacing `vector<bool>` with `basic_string<bool>` or `vector<size_t>` works just fine. Why not `vector<bool>`?